# How to substitute a value of tabe name in sql query with bat script

Tags: sql, batch-file

```
Executor_Scrubbing.bat

FOR /F "tokens=1,2,3,4 delims=" %%G IN (SchemaList.txt) DO (call SQL_Execute.bat %%G %%H %%I %%J)

SQL_Execute.bat

SET "usr=%1"
SET "pwd=%2"
SET "COMP_ID=%3"
SET "dbsvr=%4"

mkdir %usr%_%dbsvr%
sqlplus -S %usr%/%pwd%@%dbsvr% @.\query.sql %3 >.\%usr%_%dbsvr%\log.txt

schemalist.txt 

QATEST3 "hho#R^34DtsX*jX" SWC QA12F
QATEST4 "NZUOYJPD" CHM QA12F

query.sql

SELECT * FROM "&1"LBLDESCS WHERE LANG_ID = (SELECT LANGUAGECODE FROM LANGUAGE WHERE LANGUAGENAME = 'en-US');
```

- Explanation-

Executor_Scrubbing.bat calls SQL_Execute.bat and sql script mention in SQL_Execute.bat gets executed on schema listed in text file
        Problem is i want to replace "&1"LBLDESCS as SWCLBLDESCS in sql query. so this SWC will be taken from schemalist.txt. again for 2nd time "&1"LBLDESCS should get replace by CHM as CHMLBLDESCS

Comment: `SELECT * FROM &1LBLDESCS WHERE …` (remove double quotes)? I suppose that ˙… delims=˙ missing space in `FOR /F "tokens=1,2,3,4 delims= " %%G …` is merely a key mistake.

Comment: Its working .. need to use 
 
SELECT * FROM &1.LBLDESCS